# Howe can I change more than one SVG fill in react

Tags: reactjs, svg, components, fill

I am trying to change the color of two elements in an SVG in react .
I turned the svg into a component and and am trying to change the fills of both circles in my SVG (different colored fills). Changing one element is easy since there is only one class but what happens when there are two ?
I have been able to change the opacity for both elements using CSS but even changing both elements' fill has not been successful. ideas ?

- How do we change multiple fills of an SVG in react using a button ?

// App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Circles from "./circles";
const App = () => {

  const [ball, setBall] = useState("old");

  const changeStyle = () => {
    setBall("new");
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className={ball} height="100px">
        <Circles />
        <button className="btn" onClick={changeStyle}>
          Click me!
        </button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
export default App;
```

//SVG component

```
import React,{Component} from "react";

export default class Circles extends Component {
    render(){
        return (
<svg  height="500px" width="250px" id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 62.5 362.5"><defs>
    </defs><circle className="cls-1" fill="#00FF00" cx="31.25" cy="31.25" r="31.25"/><circle className="cls-2" fill="Blue" cx="31.25" cy="181.25" r="31.25"/></svg>

        )
    }
}
```

//css

```
.old {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 150px;
  fill:green
}

.new {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 150px;
  fill-opacity: .5;
}
```

Comment: Changing fill is tricky. In some cases. When you have fill defined inline it won't be override by CSS.

Answer (score 0):

On button click apply different class for each svg. so using diffrent class you can customized each svg css  Try this code may be it's helps you

// Circles

```
const Circles = ({ isnewCss }) => {
  return (
    <svg height="500px" width="250px" id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 62.5 362.5">
      <defs></defs>
      <circle className={isnewCss ? 'cls-1 new' : 'cls-1 old'} fill="#00FF00" cx="31.25" cy="31.25" r="31.25" />
      <circle className={isnewCss ? 'cls-2 new1' : 'cls-2 old1'} fill='blue' cx="31.25" cy="181.25" r="31.25" />
    </svg>
  )
}
```

//App

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

const App = () => {
  const [isnewCss, isSetNewCss] = useState(false);

  const changeStyle = () => {
    isSetNewCss(true);
  };

  return (
    <div height="100px">
      <Circles isnewCss={isnewCss} />
      <button className="btn" onClick={changeStyle}>
        Click me!
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```